# How to apply security batch to Apache 2.2.15？

Tags: apache, centos, centos6

**How to apply security batch to Apache 2.2.15？**

・CentOS 6.8

・Apache 2.2.15

[CVE-2011-3192-2.2.19-byterange-fixes.patch](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/patches/apply_to_2.2.19/)

---

```
# cd /usr/local/src
# wget http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/patches/apply_to_2.2.19/CVE-2011-3192-2.2.19-byterange-fixes.patch
```

How can I do from here?

Comment: I think that's just a diff on changes made. How did you originally install Apache?

Comment: If the patch is for v2.2.19 you cannot apply it to v2.2.15 (unless you check the source code manually and ensure it still makes the right changes).

Comment: @cgTag。I originally install Apache by yum install httpd.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to run `yum upgrade httpd`?

Comment: @cgTag。I tried yum upgrade httpd,but because CentOS6 is no more upgrade.

Comment: That is a pain. Sorry I can't help :(